# Retrieving Monthly Hits From Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics

What I want to do is grab the last 5 months including the current months hits for that month.

I have only just copied the tracking code and plugged it into my site but after that I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Five months from when you placed the code in operation and Google showed it was validated and had gathered the first 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to find out the last 5 months worth of hits after placing the tracking code on the page. You can't do that. Only after placing the tracking code on your page will you be able to see the hits. If you placed the tracking code over 5 months ago, then you should be able to see the hits, it's pretty clear.